# Как использовать в XPath выражении переменную в XMLTable?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Как использовать в XPath выражении переменную в `XMLTable`?

Например:

```
XMLTable('root/level1', PASSING xmlContent 
    COLUMNS initial_value varchar2(100) PATH '/abc/[контракт=$count]/initialValue] 
)
```

Как подставить значение время выполнения `$count`?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to use XPath with a variable in Oracle XMLTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13947416) от участника [@sojin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388889/sojin)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13947416

Answer (score 2):

Можно передавать переменные, просто их надо определить в `PASSING` выражении:

```
with tab (xml) as (
    select xmltype ('
        <abc>
            <def>
                <contract>1</contract>
                <oper>abc</oper>
            </def>
            <def>
                <contract>2</contract>
                <oper>cdf</oper>
            </def>
        </abc>') from dual) 
select u.* 
from tab, XMLTable ('/abc/def[contract=$contrno]'
    passing xml, 2 as "contrno" columns 
        contract int path 'contract',
        oper varchar2 (8) path 'oper') u
/
```

Результат:

```
  CONTRACT OPER    
---------- --------
         2 cdf
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948728) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>